# Update array list in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I Have a list of User objects. I have already override the equal and hash methods. I want to verify if a new user is already in the list, if not I want to add it, if yes, I want to update the lastTimeSeen attribute and if a user is not seen during the last 5 seconds I want to delete him from the List.

```
public void updateUserList(String firstname, String lastname, String age, Long ts)
    {
        User newUser= new User(firstname, lastname, age,ts);
        if(!listUser.contains(newUser))
        listUser.add(newUser);
        for (int i = 0; i < listUser.size();i++){
            //if not equal to new user and ts - listUser[i].lastTimeSeen > 10 second delete user, if equal update time ?
        }
    }
```

With this code I was able to add new user but I get confused to update or delete the old one. I am new with java, can someone tell me if my method is right or I should procced otherwise ?

Comment: better (performance-wise) use a `Map` for this particular task.

Comment: You have to use Iterator because the size of the list will change when you will remove element.

Comment: for this matter, if you redefined equals() you should use a collection based on `Set` that will automatically detect duplicates based on `equals()`method. Furthermore your "remove old users" part should probably be done elsewhere, possibly in another thread.

Comment: I`d suggest to iterate over the user list and check that the current user name and lastname with the one that you are adding are equal (Or compare Id). Then, you can modify the current user lastTimeSeenTime.

Comment: The use case that you describe demands a `Map` or `Set` for optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

You must override the `equals` method in `User` class, and then impliment this method:

```
/**
* This method find the user in a user list.
* return null if no any user was found.
**/
private User findUser(ArrayList<User> listUser, User user) {
    for (User u : listUser) {
        if (u.equals(user)) {
            return u;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can also override `add` method while you create new `ArrayList` as this example:

```
ArrayList<User> listUser = new ArrayList<User>() {
    @Override
    public boolean add(User user) {
        User u = findUser(this, user);
        if (u != null) {
             //udating this user on list
             return false;
        }
        return super.add(user);
    }
};
```

Now, you can modify method `updateUserList`:

```
public void updateUserList(String firstname, String lastname, String age, Long ts) {
    listUser.add(new User(firstname, lastname, age, ts));    
}
```

I'm NOT in an IDE now and my answer maybe incorrect.